# lighttpd.conf on different folder

Tags: lighttpd

I have vps. i have installed lighttpd, my conf file is on the
`/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`

Then I installed phpmyadmin using `apt-get` which writes a new `lighttpd.conf` automatically on `/etc/phpmyadmin/lighttpd.conf`

The weird thing is, I can't find anything on `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` the syntax that related to phpmyadmin.

Don't get me wrong, the server is alright, just wondering how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The `postinst` script of the DEB package for phpMyAdmin creates a symbolic link in `/etc/lighttpd/conf-available/` (and `/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/`) which points to `/etc/phpmyadmin/lighttpd.conf`.

Inside the `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` the contents of `/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/` are loaded.